# Diferença de performance de uma aplicação com cenários idênticos

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, magento

Neste fim de semana fizemos deploy de uma aplicação com base no framework Magento, que foi exaustivamente testada em vários cenários, com alta carga de usuários fazendo várias requisições ao banco de dados, como consultas, atualizações e inserções, todo o percurso dos clientes finais foi simulado.

Nos testes as configurações eram idênticas as que estavam na hora do deploy, a única diferença era o subdomínio, que estavamos usando um de homologação e depois apontamos para o www, e para nossa surpresa a aplicação ficou totalmente instável, apresentando erros de banco de dados, na verdade apenas um erro:

```
MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away
```

Este erro ocorreu em diversas tabelas, e na aplicação de testes não ocorreu nem uma vez, com 50 usuários simultâneos fazendo compras, e na hora do deploy estavamos com 20 usuários (segundo o analytics).

A configuração da infra é:

- 2 Web servers
- 1 File server
- RDS
- Servidor para Redis

A pergunta é: Como é possível que em casos idênticos de configuração a aplicação se comportou tão diferente? o subdomínio tem alguma influência nisto?

Obs: se precisarem de mais detalhes, favor solicitar

Obrigado

Comment: O subdomínio não influencia. Usa Docker? Como sabe que é idêntico?

Comment: Não utilizamos Docker.

Sei que é idêntico pois homologamos no subdomínio teste o projeto, com uma infra X, que era composta pelos itens que citei na pergunta, na hora do lançamento simplesmente apontamos para ela o subdomínio www, entende?

Esqueci de citar que temos um haproxy para o load balance dos webservers.

Comment: Cara muito estranho mesmo, eu passei por uma situação parecida uma vez ( ficar dando error 2006) Para corrigir, alterei a variável mysql wait_timeout no arquivo de configuração my.cnf,  se o mysqld recebe um pacote que é muito grande ou incorreto, ele assume que algo deu errado com o cliente e fecha a conexão. Para corrigir, tambémn da para aumentar o limite máximo do pacote max_allowed_packet, por exemplo, max_allowed_packet = 128M e reiniciar o MYSQL, o bizarro é você só ter apontado do subdomínio para o domínio e ele começar a pipocar.